# How to sort fetched request result in the opposite direction?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have entity Message. Each message contains timestamp. I want to show only 20 last messages at once, from the oldest to the newest one.

To get last 20 I do the following code

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Message" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:20];
NSSortDescriptor *timeDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"time" ascending:NO] autorelease];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:timeDescriptor];
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"data" cacheName:nil] autorelease];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
```

But in the result I want to show ascending:YES. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: do u have find a clean solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just take the total # and subtract the current row to get a reverse sort. So 0 -> 20, 1 -> 19, ... 20 -> 0. Assuming you are using a tableView with 1 section the code would look like (untested):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:0];
NSInteger reverseRow = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects] - indexPath.row - 1;
NSIndexPath *reverseIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:reverseRow inSection:indexPath.section];    
id myObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:reverseIndexPath];
}
```